# When making Android release build getting gradle warning - AGPBI: Class missing

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

**Note: Build is getting generated successfully**

When I make a release build its shows this warning.

**-Task :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease**

**AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing class: net.sf.cglib.proxy.CallbackFilter","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}**

Tried to keep this class **(net.sf.cglib.proxy.CallbackFilter)** in the proguard file, which doesn't solve the problem

Why is this warning coming and how we can remove this warning with proper setup?

Answer (score 0):

This was reported but closed without comments

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/4975